# Calculate average for a sequence of strings, then remove anything greater than 2SD of the average in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, stringr

**I have a large dataset of over 10,000 rows: df:**

```
  User              duration

  amy                582         
  amy                27
  amy                592
  amy                16
  amy                250
  tom                33
  tom                10
  tom                40
  tom                100
```

**Desired output:**

```
User               duration

amy                 582
amy                 592
amy                 250
tom                 33
tom                 10
tom                 40
```

Essentially, this will be removing any outliers that are 2SD from each unique User mean.
The code would take the mean of each unique user, determine its mean and standard deviation and then remove values that are > 2SD of the mean.

**dput:**

```
structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("amy", "tom"), class = "factor"), duration = c(582L, 
27L, 592L, 16L, 250L, 33L, 10L, 40L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
first define average and standard deviation


      ave = ave(df$duration)
      sd =  sd(df$duration)
```

And then set some sort of parameter to this:

```
     for i in df {
     remove all if > 2*sd}
```

I am not sure and would like some suggestions.

Comment: Your formula translates to `df %>% group_by(User) %>% filter(duration < (mean(duration) + 2 * sd(duration)))`

Comment: let me try this please

Comment: but it will not give the expected output you showed because mean + 2* sd iss 861 for 'amy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`, which would be much concise when used with `between`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(User) %>%
   filter(between(duration, mean(duration) -  sd(duration), 
                           mean(duration) +   sd(duration)))
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this, but I still see all the original values- maybe I can modify a bit

Comment: @TanishaHudson As I mentioned, based on your logic, the values are not filtering out

Comment: Ok, I must be doing something wrong then. When I modified it to 1SD it works! This works thank you! I need to recheck my 2SD calculation

Comment: Hello @akrun, I am getting some strange error on my end- I am not sure what this means: Error in as.double(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(duration) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA   - I have googled this, but am still unsure

Comment: @TanishaHudson is it based on the same data

Comment: yes, I am trying to do this same command today - two columns User and duration

Comment: @TanishaHudson. can you try on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` loaded and your example from that `dput`

Comment: @TanishaHudson i tested. again, but couldn't find any error on my side

Comment: oh wow it works now @akrun wow, so by just refreshing and reloading dplyr, it works. thank you

Comment: it could be that there is some package that masked. some functions from dplyr

Answer (score 2):

Here's a data.table approach, which may be faster for many rows.

```
library(data.table)
df <- structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("amy", "tom"), class = "factor"), duration = c(50000, 
582, 27, 592, 16, 250, 33, 10, 40, 100)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")
df
   User duration
1   amy    50000
2   amy      582
3   amy       27
4   amy      592
5   amy       16
6   amy      250
7   tom       33
8   tom       10
9   tom       40
10  tom      100
```

**Code**

```
setDT(df)[,.SD[duration <= mean(duration) + (2 * sd(duration)) &
               duration >= mean(duration) - (2 * sd(duration)),]
          ,by=User]
   User duration
1:  amy      582
2:  amy       27
3:  amy      592
4:  amy       16
5:  amy      250
6:  tom       33
7:  tom       10
8:  tom       40
9:  tom      100
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this, but I still see all the original values

Comment: I think your issue is that you don't have any values in the example data that are more than 2 SD away from the mean. I've edited my answer with an example.

Comment: yes your absolutely correct, I was wrong. Your code works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scale()` to find the z score and keep absolute values less than 2:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  filter(abs(scale(duration)) < 2)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   User [2]
  User  duration
  <fct>    <int>
1 amy        582
2 amy         27
3 amy        592
4 amy         16
5 amy        250
6 tom         33
7 tom         10
8 tom         40
9 tom        100
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using the `mutate` and `filter` functions in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(User) %>% mutate(ave_plus2sd=ave(duration)+2*sd(duration)) %>% 
filter(duration < ave_plus2sd)
```

> This will give you the following output which allows comparison of each entry with average + 2*sd for the user.

```
# Groups:   User [2]
  User  duration ave_plus2sd
  <fct>    <int>       <dbl>
1 amy        582        861.
2 amy         27        861.
3 amy        592        861.
4 amy         16        861.
5 amy        250        861.
6 tom         33        122.
7 tom         10        122.
8 tom         40        122.
9 tom        100        122.
```

We can further add `%>% select (User,duration)` to select the columns of interest User and duration.